# Jquery edit html link display name

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I has a slight issue where we are using a wiki tool and the links are created between pages automatically using internal links.
I wish to style these links with a simple button, to do this i just want to add a  wrapping around the display name of the link.

```
<a href="example.php">Display Name</a>
```

I want to make it like this:

```
<a href="example.php"><div class="class">Display Name</div></a>
```

I am thinking i may be able to do this with jquery but i am not sure of how to complete this.
If someone could please point me in the correct direction.

I look looked into append and not sure how i can use it just for that one element.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you could simply get the text and wrap it however you like:

```
var $links = $('a');
if ($links.length) {
    $links.each(function(k,v) {
        var text = $(v).text();
        $(v).html('<span class="some-class">' + text + '</span>');
    });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/my7qdyek/)

There are quite a few ways to go about it.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect of this issue i have currently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JQuery `.wrapInner`. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) are the docs.

```
$('a[href="example.php"]').wrapInner('<div class="class"></div>');
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers another issue i have with a very simple fix.